# Rigidbody and Rigidbody2D why does conditional operator not work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, casting

So, know I am writing a method which takes the argument Rigidbody and its overloaded method which takes Rigidbody2D. The problem is I know I can use their parent class "Component" and give the reference that way, but when i try to cast it again in the designated class, I can't make it work. For know this is the code

```
    protected void Exit(bool isEventType, ContactInfo info, GameObject obj, Rigidbody rb)
    {
        if (!EventPassesFilter(isEventType, info, obj, rb != null,
            rb != null ? rb.velocity : Vector3.zero
        )) return;
        if (contact.ContainsKey(obj)) contact.Remove(obj);
        InitializeEvent(info);
    }

    protected void Exit(bool isEventType, ContactInfo info, GameObject obj, Rigidbody2D rb)
    {
        if (!EventPassesFilter(isEventType, info, obj, rb != null,
            rb != null ? rb.velocity : Vector2.zero
        )) return;
        if (contact.ContainsKey(obj)) contact.Remove(obj);
        InitializeEvent(info);
    }
```

But i know i can combine them and make something like this.

```
    protected void Exit(bool isEventType, ContactInfo info, GameObject obj, Component rb1)
    {
        var rb = rb1.GetType() == typeof(Rigidbody) ? rb1 as Rigidbody : rb1 as Rigidbody2D;
        if (!EventPassesFilter(isEventType, info, obj, rb != null,
            rb != null ? rb.velocity : Vector3.zero
        )) return;
        if (contact.ContainsKey(obj)) contact.Remove(obj);
        InitializeEvent(info);
    }
```

But it keeps telling me that :

> There is no implicit conversion between `UnityEngine.Rigidbody` and
> `UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D`

Can you recommend anything?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
protected void Exit(bool isEventType, ContactInfo info, GameObject obj, Component rb1)
{
    if(rb1.GetType() == typeof(Rigidbody))        
        var rb = rb1 as Rigidbody;        
    else        
        var rb = rb1 as Rigidbody2D;
    
    if (!EventPassesFilter(isEventType, info, obj, rb != null,
        rb != null ? rb.velocity : Vector3.zero
    )) return;
    if (contact.ContainsKey(obj)) contact.Remove(obj);
    InitializeEvent(info);
}
```

The problem (I think) is that `var` is an *implicit variable*, which should be initialized. And ternary operator doesn't allow to do that **in one-branch condition**.

Comment: `var` can absolutely be used with ternary operators, the issue is that ternary operators must return the same (or implicitly castable) types from both branches. Also would `rb` not go out of scope as soon as it was declared in your example?

Comment: @Jake maybe my explanation wasn't clear, when I say "doesn't allow to do that" I'm refering that cannot have two different types on the same branch, I was trying to specify it in "cause the class-initialization will change on runtime", I'll update the answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that ternary operators *must* return the same type from both of their branches (or types that can be implicitly converted between such as `int` and `float`)

`Rigidbody` and `Rigidbody2D` cannot be implicitly converted between so a ternary operator will not work here, you will need to expand this to a regular `if/else` block, or write some kind of interface yourself